# Android Emulator Process killed

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to run emulator on android studio 4 but after sometime it says: 
"Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD MyDevice_API_29 was killed."

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS97p.jpg)

Comment: Try wiping the data of your AVD

Comment: Yes I did... I even remove every image(R:_86....etc..) and reinstalled them..but still my issue is not resolved